# How to query using Mysql Row Constructors in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The following MySQL queries are equivalent:

```
select * from TableA where (column1, column2) in ( ('name1', 60), ('name2', 65) )
select * from TableA where (column1='name1' and column2=60) or (column1='name2' and column2=65)
```

However, the power of the Row Constructor form (ie 1st example) is that you can use it to leverage to handle querying an any length list of pairs of values.  Without it you have to write dynamic sql which is a security risk.  Using the first form avoids that nasty problem.

However, how do you represent this in JDBC using prepared statemtents?  For example:

```
Connection connection = ...
PreparedStatement smt = connection.preparedStatement("select * from TableA where (column1,column2) in ?");
smt.setObject(1, whatDataTypeGoesHere );
smt.execute();
```

I've looked into `setArray`, but how to represent the `column1` and `column2` values in the values of the array?  I'm wondering if `SQLData` interface might serve as that conduit.  But reading the docs I can't see how that might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, MySQL's implementation in Connector/J does not support `setArray()`. It throws `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`.

Even if it did implement `setArray()`, I have not used it and I haven't seen any documentation showing examples of using that method for row constructors instead of scalar types. It may be that it is not the right solution for the task you have.

I think you'll have to write a string-builder-something-something to do what you want. It's okay to write code that builds an SQL query. It's only an SQL injection risk if you use untrusted content in the SQL query string. If you only use content that is strictly under control of your own code, you can ensure that it is not dangerous.

For example, in the following example, the content interpolated into the SQL string is based only on string literals in the calling code. No content from an untrusted source is used.

```
String placeHolders = String.join(",",
  Collections.nCopies(params.size(), "(?, ?)"));
String sql = "select * from TableA where (column1, column2) in ( (" 
  + placeHolders + ")";
```

(Assuming `params` is an array of objects from which you get the values corresponding to colum1 & column2.)

This will result in an SQL string like

```
select * from TableA where (column1, column2) in ((?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), ...)
```

Then you have to loop over your array of params you want to bind, and set `setString()` twice per loop.

Comment: I do have capabilities to write dynamic sql in a safe way as I have a DSL in my project that handles the escaping and such, but since this option is potentially available I wanted to explore it.  Writing a scalar value `in` query in JDBC is somewhat mysterious to track down; this seemed completely unknown.  I suppose it still is.

Comment: My observation is that it's hard enough to spread the word to get programmers to use query parameters even for simple queries. Many programmers cling to the outdated and error-prone technique of concatenating query strings together with `+`.